# My delete function will not work using react

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, ecmascript-6

Delete button Not working using react

I can do axios call to delete in postman but when I try to do it on the front-end in react, my delete function will not work.

```
<button onSubmit = {this.handleSubmit}> Delete </button>
```

---

```
// below is the function I'm trying to use to delete an item from my database

async handleSubmit(event)  { 
        event.preventDefault()
        await axios.delete(`http://localhost:3000/brands/${this.props.match.params.brand_id}/guitars/${this.props.match.params.id}`)
      console.log("pressed")
    }

// the backend is built in ruby and in postman the delete route works
```

I don't understand why the button is not working.

I expected to receive an error when I refreshed the page because the specific item (guitar) and url is no longer in the database, OR, my redirect route will work and I will be redirected to the page showing all items (guitars) of the particular brand.

Comment: my button: <button onSubmit = {this.handleSubmit}> </button>

Comment: What's the error that you're getting?

Answer (score 0):

Change to onClick not onSubmit. Button dont have onSubmit event

```
 async handleSubmit(event)  { 
      event.preventDefault()
      await axios.delete()
      console.log("pressed")
  }


  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <Hello name={this.state.name} />
        <p>
          Start editing to see some magic happen :)
        </p>
         <button onClick={(e) => this.handleSubmit(e)}> Delete </button>
      </div>
    );
  }
```

Code [here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-mctatn)